# MDX - rewrite a query using scope

Tags: scope, mdx, hierarchy

I have an `MDX` query

```
IIF
(
  IsLeaf([PnL].[PnL_A].CurrentMember)
 ,
  [Measures].[PnL - Plan] * [PnL].[Flag 5].CurrentMember.MemberValue
 ,Sum
  (
    [PnL].[PnL_A].CurrentMember.Children
   ,[Measures].[PnL- Plan (signed)]
  )
)
```

What it does: 
The whole thing represents profit and loss. Unfortunately, it is constructed in a way that there are two columns: value of a profit or loss, and flag in the other column.

So if the flag (`[PnL].[Flag 5]`) is set to `-1`, the value (`[Measures].[PnL - Plan]`) is a loss, if the flag is a `1` - the value is a profit. I can't change that.

The query finds leaves of the hierarchy (single deepest source of a profit or loss) and multiplies the flag with the value. For non-leaf members it just aggregates it's leaves.

My problem is that it works too slow - I wanted to rewrite this query using `SCOPE` but I have no idea how.

Comment: `IIF` will work in block mode if you have one branch set to `null`.

Comment: @whytheq Hello ! Could you elaborate? I don't fully understand your comment

Comment: All I mean is that when using `IIF` it is better to use with one of the logical branches set to `null` then you are more likely to get the benefit of block-mode calculation. So either this `IIF(test,null,x)` or this `IIF(test,x, null)`. Just not sure how you can use this approach with your problem.

Comment: @whytheq the SCOPE is said to achieve better performace when it comes to subcubes. Do you know how to rewrite this query using this statement? I can't really see a way of using IIF without the third argument in my problem

Comment: Sorry - I just query our cubes and I do not get involved with the cube script itself so I have no experience setting up scoped assignments. Maybe Sourav will be able to help - he is very active on this forum.

Answer (score 0):

Since I have absolutely no idea on your cube structure, let's say your member structure is

**`Pnl-->Pnl_A-->NonLeaf-->Leaf`**

You could define scope as below -

```
CREATE MEMBER CurrentCube.[Measures].[ProfitOrLossValue] AS NULL;

//Current member is leaf and Flag5 is 1
SCOPE
     (
      [Measures].[ProfitOrLossValue], 
      [PnL].[Flag 5].&[1], 
      [PnL].[PnL_A].[Leaf].[All].CHILDREN
     );

This = [Measures].[PnL - Plan];
END SCOPE;

SCOPE
     (
      [Measures].[ProfitOrLossValue], 
      [PnL].[Flag 5].&[-1], 
      [PnL].[PnL_A].[Leaf].[All].CHILDREN
     );

This = ([Measures].[PnL - Plan] * -1);
END SCOPE;

//Current member is non-leaf
SCOPE
     (
      [Measures].[ProfitOrLossValue], 
      [PnL].[PnL_A].[NonLeaf].[All].CHILDREN
     );

This = Sum
          (
           [PnL].[PnL_A].CurrentMember.Children, 
           [Measures].[PnL- Plan (signed)]
          );
END SCOPE;
```

Hope it helps.